# Labeling Groups From ModelBuilder tool in Geoprocessing Pane using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

Is there a way to group the geoprocessing steps of a ModelBuilder model in the geoprocessing pane?

I am building a model that creates a new feature class and then allows the user to append existing layers to that new feature class. However, when I open the model as a geoprocessing tool, it is difficult to see which parameters are meant for which step without really looking into each tool.

Is there a way to provide a header or label for each section in the geoprocessing pane?

I want to be able to label one section "Create New Feature Class" and the other "Append to New Feature Class" where each step starts. I thought grouping and labeling in the model itself would help, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS Pro when you expose inputs and outputs of tools as parameters in a model they become the parameters you see on a geoprocessing pane when you run the model as a *Model Tool*.

Grouping tools as you have shown in your screenshot has no affect on the parameter order when the model is run as a tool, it's purely a visual nicety in model builder itself.

What you can do in ArcGIS Pro (but not ArcMap) is group parameters into collapsible [categories](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/model-parameters.htm#) by giving them a name in the properties dialog of the model.

[image: Properties]